# StyleCop.Analyzers Nuget Dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget, stylecop

I have created a Nuget package on a private Azure Artifacts environment, that houses a custom configuration for StyleCop.Analyzers so that the configuration for coding standards can be centralised. This all works absolutely fine and can be installed in other projects with no issue.

I have a separate class library which is being built into a Nuget package, and this project utilises my custom StyleCop package. This package also builds correctly, but in the list of dependencies is my custom StyleCop.Analyzers package. This means that everywhere the class library gets installed, the custom StyleCop.Analyzers package will be installed as well. I don't feel this is correct as it is purely a development-scoped package and should not be included as an actual dependency.

The class library does not feature a `.nuspec` file, everything is handled through the `.csproj` and some Azure Pipeline's wizardry. Is the dependency chain correct, or is there something that can be done to ensure that the custom StyleCop.Analyzers package is not listed as a dependency?

Comment: You could consider implementing your analyzers as a submodule instead of a Nuget package? This is how we solved our custom analyzer problem. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you add `<devDependency>true</devDependency>` node to the `.nuspec` file then the dependency does not get shipped to packages that consume it.